# Undock toolbar with pywinauto?

Tags: python, automation, keyboard-shortcuts, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a tedious old 2000s proprietary program for a client.

So far, it's been a successful run overall except for when trying to access elements within a *docked toolbar*. There are *two of them* nested in a **pane** located in the main window.

I couldn't reach the toolbars through their **mother pane**, the pane keeps showing it has no children. And so I was unable to access the elements in *the toolbars* nested in it. That was until I tried undocking *them*, and now suddenly *they* show up in the window tree and can be accessed with *their* respective elements.

My previous temporary solution was to use `window.click(coords=(x,y))` but that proved terrible when put to test, too many variables that can break the automation.

So how can I automate undocking *the toolbars*, so that they are visible by pywinauto?

P.s: I used Accessibility Insights at first because I wasn't able to learn anything about the contents of *the toolbars* through pywinauto.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide code as well as the `dump_tree()` of the application controls to understand it better.